# Filtering inside Django Rest Framework field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following Model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    """
    Describe a Project
    """
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    classroom = models.ManyToMany(Classroom)
    ...
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    classroom = models.ForeignKey(Classroom)
```

A Project is belonging to multiple classroom. A user can attach tags to projects depending of the classroom. For example:

```
Classroom A:
Project 1 -> Tags:Math,English
Classroom B:
Project 1 -> Tags:English
```

I designed an API with Django Rest Framework to get Projects and their associated tags.

```
Request: GET /api/projects/1
Response: 
{
   "name":"Project 1",
   "id": 1,
   "classroom" : [
       "ClassroomA","ClassroomB"
   ],
   "tags":[
       "Math","English"
   ]
}
```

What I need to achieve is, when I'm filetring on the classroom, to only have related tags in my reponse for example:

```
Request: GET /api/projects/1/?classroom=ClassroomA
Response: 
{
   "name":"Project 1",
   "id": 1,
   "classroom" : [
       "ClassroomA"
   ],
   "tags":[
       "Math","English"
   ]
}

Request: GET /api/projects/1/?classroom=ClassroomB
Response: 
{
   "name":"Project 1",
   "id": 1,
   "classroom" : [
       "ClassroomB"
   ],
   "tags":[
       "English"
   ]
}
```

I'm able to filter API results but I'm not able to filter inside of each fields depending of the classroom in the GET parameters:

```
# serializers.py
class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    classroom = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True, slug_field='name')
    tags = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, slug_field='name', read_only=True)

# filter.py
import django_filters
from ...models import Project

class ProjectFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    classroom = django_filters.CharFilter(name="classroom__name")

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['classroom']

# views.py
class SimViewSet(ReadProductPermission, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProjectSerializer
    filter_class = ProjectFilter
    queryset = Project.objects.all()
```

Do you have any idea how I can perform this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create more complex filtering using a [`MethodFilter`](https://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/filters.html#methodfilter).